# After i create the web, what happened then?

Tags: javascript, html, web-services, web

I’ve just creat a web game by a video tutorial(I’m learning html-css-js).
Now I have created it, how can I make the web game to have a link, so I can show to others with a link my web game.

Thank you!!

Comment: *I think* your asking how do you host your HTML? If that is the case you need some kind of web server

Comment: @Liam how can I do that in vs code

Comment: vs code isn't a web server, so you can't do that in visual studio code. I'd suggest you start by googling what a web server is

Comment: @Liam I just saw it, and I know what web server is, but the process from vs code to web server what is it?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. Hosting html has **literally** nothing to do with VS code. If you know what a web server is, then set one up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many ways to show your work to friends.
1. Actually host your game by registering a domain name and hosting. This way everyone can search web and find your game.
 check [netlify](https://netlify.com) they provide free hosting, you just need to have a [github](https://github.com) repo of your game or otherwise you can just upload entire folder on their site.

2.You can also try online code editors like [codepen](https://codepen.io), [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) and share urls of your code.

Answer (score -1):

You need to host it on a server. In my opinion, the easiest way is to use a cloud provider (AWS, GCP, Azure) host it on an instance and get a public IP. You can go ahead and register it with a domain.

Comment: I’m using the vs code btw

Comment: VS Code is just a text editor. You need to "host" your code on a server. It's not a stackoverflow answer, it's an entire project. Read through this [link](https://www.hostgator.in/blog/how-to-host-a-website-a-complete-guide-for-beginners/)